# Why is ConvertFrom-Json returning a string

Tags: json, powershell

I thought that the example should have given a name of PSCustomObject so what's going on?

```
$body = '{ "val1": "jim", "val2": "james"}'

$json = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $body

$json.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name    BaseType
-------- -------- ----    --------
True     True     String  System.Object
```

I'm trying to iterate through the items in a json object and spent hours getting nowhere.

Comment: Returns a `PSCustomObject` for me, what PowerShell version are you running?

Comment: Tried on Win 10/PS 5.1 returns  PSCustomObject. What return $json?

Comment: Did you statically type `$json` to a string earlier in the script with `[string]$json = "example"` ? What happens when you `Remove-Variable json` right before `$json = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $body`?

Comment: @BenH I can only assume you're right as it's working perfectly for me now to, even in the original script. Sigh!